# Is there any dependency between config/environments/*.rb files and config/deploy/*.rb files? If yes,does it impact Capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, capistrano3

I am trying to understand how different pieces of configuration files work together behind the scene. Especially the configurations related to environments/*.rb and deploy/*.rb files. I know that config/environments directory is created by rails and config/deploy is created by capistrano. My understanding is that these two sets of configurations have different purposes. Just wanted to clear my understanding, if these two sets of configuration interact with each other in anyway while running the application with rails or deploying the application. TIA.

Comment: `environments/.rb` contain settings used when running the rails application (server, test, console, etc). `config/deploy` is for the configuration of deploying the application to the production server (things like for example the version control system, FTP etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not directly related, but do interact.

As previously answered, `config/environment/*.rb` contains settings specific to an environment. This is evaluated when Rails boots.

`config/deploy.rb` contains general Capistrano deployment configuration. Usually, it's useful to create a set of specific configuration for some deployment situation, in which case you define files in `config/deploy/*.rb`. The most common situation is to deploy differently for different environments. This is where the two can interact.

For example, if you have a staging environment going to one set of servers and a production environment going to a different set of servers, you would likely define `config/deploy/staging.rb` and `config/deploy/production.rb`. These would define the servers to which they go, and are triggered by running `cap stagename deploy`, where `stagename` is the name of the file in `config/deploy/*.rb` (without the file extension).

In `config/deploy/*.rb` files, you can also define the rails environment to be used by Rails commands run during deployment, such as asset compilation and Bundler installation. You do this by adding the line `set :rails_env, 'staging'`, where `staging` is the name of a file in `config/environments/*.rb` (again, without the file extension).

However, while in the above example, there is a 1:1 correlation between the two files, there doesn't always need to be. For example, if you inject all environment specific configuration via environment variables, you might have staging and production files in `config/deploy/`, but only a production file in `config/environments/`. In this case, you would have staging Rails run as production. You would need to define `set :rails_env, 'production'` in this case, probably in `config/deploy.rb`.

One additional caveat is that if you use the `capistrano-rails` gem and don't explicitly define the `rails_env` setting in your deployment configuration, [it will guess the Rails environment based on the stage name](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/set_rails_env.rake) (the name of the file invoked on deployment, e.g. `cap stagename deploy`). So you might be misled into thinking that you need to have a 1:1 mapping there. However, if there is no need for another configuration file, just explicitly define `set :rails_env, 'stagename'`.

Answer (score 0):

`environment/**.rb` contains settings of your application when runs in different environments (test, development, production). `deploy/**.rb` contains settings of your applications when deployed(staging, production).